# Cron job to transfer files to remote server

Tags: 7, files

How would I go about scheduling a monthly file transfer (via FTP) to send files in a specific directory on my remote VPS to a server on my internal Corporate network? Once files are transferred, I'd also like to job to delete the files on the VPS?

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutely need it, Drupal has [`hook_cron()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7.x) for regular task running:

```
function MYMODULE_cron() {
  // Copy your files here using standard php FTP functions
}
```

But it would be considerably more efficient to leave Drupal out of this altogether, and set it up with a basic rsync/FTP cron job executed on the server.

Alternatively, [Backup and Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) can both take a dump of the public/private file system and transfer it to an FTP target. Again, a solution outside Drupal will always be more efficient as it won't bootstrap the application.

Comment: Thanks Clive but I've never written a module or used hook_cron().

Comment: If you don't want to develop a solution Backup and Migrate also has automatic scheduled backups built in. As I mentioned, it's not as efficient as writing your own solution, but if you don't want to do that it's certainly an alternative

Comment: Thanks Clive, I use Backup and Migrate for my database but I don't see a way to backup my public files to an FTP server, just NodeSquirrel which is a paid service?

Comment: Sorry I haven't actually used it myself, the module page does say explicitly: _Backup to FTP/S3/Email or NodeSquirrel.com_, that's what I was going off. Maybe there's a submodule that needs to be enabled? Or one of the other complementary modules listed on the module page?